# How do I set focus to an entry widget from a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a class with several functions, one of them throws an exception and I would like to set the focus back to the entry widget it is validating. calling:

```
self.entryWidget.set_focus()
```

returns an AttributeError:

```
'App' object has no attribute 'entryWidget'
```

How can should I refer to this widget outside of `__init__`?

```
class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        calcframe = Frame(master)
        calcframe.pack()
        self.vol = DoubleVar()
        entryWidget = Entry(calcframe, textvariable=self.vol)
        entryWidget.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        entryWidget.focus()

    def updateSIP(self):
        try:
            volume = self.vol.get()
        except:
            self.entryWidget.set_focus()
root = Tk()
root.wm_title('title')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not making `entryWidget` an attribute of `App`.

To do this, place `self.` before it:

```
def __init__(self,master):
    calcframe = Frame(master)
    calcframe.pack()
    self.vol = DoubleVar()
    self.entryWidget = Entry(calcframe, textvariable=self.vol)
    self.entryWidget.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    self.entryWidget.focus()
```

Now, `entryWidget` is an attribute of `App` and can be accessed through `self`.